# Separate consecutive numbers from an array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array:

```
(array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,
         14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,
         27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,
         75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,
         88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100,
        101, 102, 103, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148,
        149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161,
        162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172], dtype=int64),)
```

I want to separate consecutive numbers into separate lists. Like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 

18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,  29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
```

and

```
[70,  71,  72,  73,  74, 75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  

87, 88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103]
```

and

```
[139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 

154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172]
```

How can I achieve this in Python? Thank you.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing ,an array starts from 0 so the first element is array[0]
Likewise you can check the index and start indexing eg:
`array[0:10] ‘ would give first 10 elements, it is called slicing .

Answer (score 0):

You can use list with while loop for comparison and then appending the results to a list. Example:

```
lst = [  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,
         14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,
         27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,
         75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,
         88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100,
        101, 102, 103, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148,
        149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161,
        162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172]


i,j = 1, 0
consecutives = [[]]

while i < len(lst):
    if lst[i-1] == lst[i]-1:
        consecutives[j].append(lst[i-1])
    else:
        consecutives.append([])
        consecutives[j].append(lst[i-1])
        j += 1
    i += 1

print(consecutives)
```